# while resampling the data why it didn't resampling continous in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have temperature in a csv file. My file is updated with time . I have loaded this data to a pandas DataFrame. I changed the start time into 0 minutes

What i am trying to do is to convert this data from 0 minutes into 60 minutes 60 minutes resample the data. What i need to do is add time from starting row and read the rest of the file to a Data Frame continuously without adding start_time and end_time.

While I wrote the code for re-sample the data. It run properly only for one day time period. It didn't run for next day time value. 
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('n.csv')
data= pd.DataFrame(dataset,columns=  ['date','time','temperature','humidity','wind'])
data['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['time']) 
data['time'] -= data.at[0, 'time']
data['time'] = data['time'].dt.total_seconds()
data['time']= pd.to_datetime(data['time'], unit='s')

data = (data.set_index('time')
    .resample('60T').first()
    .reset_index()
   .reindex(columns=data.columns))
data['time'] = data['time'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9

print(data)
```

my csv file :

[image]

After replacing first time into 0 seconds then the results:

[image]

After replacing time here I want resample my data every 60 minutes. Because here I measured the values after 5min, 10 min, 15min. So I want to resample my data in every 60 minutes.

So I wrote for that code and the output is displaying below:

output:

> ```
>     date             time   temperature  humidity  wind
>       0   10/3/2018      0           63         0     0
>       1   10/3/2018   3600           63         0     2
>       2   10/3/2018   7200          104        11     0
>       3   10/3/2018  10800           93         0    50
>       4   10/3/2018  14400          177         0     2
>       5   10/3/2018  18000          133         0     0
>       6   10/3/2018  21600           70         0     0
>       7   10/4/2018  25200          210        50    20
>       8   10/5/2018  28800          170        20    40
>       9   10/3/2018  32400          127         0    50
>       10  10/3/2018  36000          205         0     0
>       11  10/3/2018  39600          298         0     0
>       12  10/3/2018  43200          234         0     0
>       13  10/3/2018  46800          148         0    20
>       14  10/3/2018  50400          135         0     0
>       15  10/3/2018  54000          100         0    50
> ```

But my code is not a good responded for my csv file data. Because it is just responding for one day data only. But I want to resample the data for each day in every 60 minutes.

Expected output:

[image]
csv file:
 [My csv file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsAtm0vSsBfOL8z42UAPAwljaO1-DSKfdD9lSu3lv80/edit#gid=35707506)

Comment: @ALollz I tried that code also. But nothing happened. Same output came.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @awa please add your expected output to the question.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, I editted my question. I hope now you can understand what I am trying to do?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I edited my question. I hope now you can understand what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to use a column having not unique values as index, and resample with it, with truncates your dataframe for a single day.

You must use a true DatetimeIndex containing both the date and the time to resample, and then use the time if you want to:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('n.csv')
data= pd.DataFrame(dataset.values, columns=['date','time','temperature',
                                    'humidity','wind'],
                   index=pd.to_datetime(dataset['date']
                                         +dataset['time'].str.rjust(9),
                                         format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
data = (data.resample('60T').first())
data['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data.index - data.index[0]).seconds

data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Simply the column `date` is not handled by above code - anyway, I really do not know what it represents now with a `time` columns that is not reset on a day boundary.

The resulting dataframe is

```
         date   time  temperature  humidity  wind
0   10/3/2018      0         63.0       0.0   0.0
1   10/3/2018   3600         63.0       0.0   2.0
2   10/3/2018   7200        104.0      11.0   0.0
3   10/3/2018  10800         93.0       0.0  50.0
4   10/3/2018  14400        177.0       0.0   2.0
5   10/3/2018  18000        133.0       0.0   0.0
6   10/3/2018  21600         70.0       0.0   0.0
7   10/3/2018  25200         83.0       0.0  60.0
8         NaN  28800          NaN       NaN   NaN
9   10/3/2018  32400        127.0       0.0  50.0
10  10/3/2018  36000        205.0       0.0   0.0
11  10/3/2018  39600        298.0       0.0   0.0
12  10/3/2018  43200        234.0       0.0   0.0
13  10/3/2018  46800        148.0       0.0  20.0
14  10/3/2018  50400        135.0       0.0   0.0
15  10/3/2018  54000        100.0       0.0  50.0
16        NaN  57600          NaN       NaN   NaN
17        NaN  61200          NaN       NaN   NaN
18        NaN  64800          NaN       NaN   NaN
19        NaN  68400          NaN       NaN   NaN
20        NaN  72000          NaN       NaN   NaN
21        NaN  75600          NaN       NaN   NaN
22        NaN  79200          NaN       NaN   NaN
23        NaN  82800          NaN       NaN   NaN
24  10/4/2018      0        166.0       0.0   0.0
25  10/4/2018   3600        130.0       0.0   0.0
26  10/4/2018   7200        120.0      10.0  10.0
27  10/4/2018  10800         80.0      40.0  20.0
28        NaN  14400          NaN       NaN   NaN
29  10/4/2018  18000         60.0      70.0  50.0
...       ...    ...          ...       ...   ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code is also great answer for my question

Comment: Simple and best answer. Thank you once again for saving my day

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the job.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

lastday = data.loc[0, 'date']
def convert_time(x):
    global lastday
    if x.date() == lastday.date():
        tm = x - lastday
        return tm.total_seconds()/60
    else:
        lastday = x
        return 0
        
data['time'] = data['date'].apply(convert_time)

data.set_index('date', inplace=True)
data = data.resample('60T').first()
```

You have `'date'` and `'time'` in different columns.
What I did here is to concatenate the strings and convert the result to datetime objects (saved in column `'date'`). Then you can do the resampling.

The `'time'` column is modified to show the time in minutes from the beginning of the day. The first row of the day (whatever time is, I noticed that is not always 6:00:00) is set to 0.

After this, using the csv you provided, `data` is:

```
                      time  temperature  humidity  wind
date                                                   
2018-10-03 06:00:00    0.0         63.0       0.0   0.0
2018-10-03 07:00:00   60.0         63.0       0.0   2.0
2018-10-03 08:00:00  120.0        104.0      11.0   0.0
2018-10-03 09:00:00  180.0         93.0       0.0  50.0
2018-10-03 10:00:00  240.0        177.0       0.0   2.0
2018-10-03 11:00:00  300.0        133.0       0.0   0.0
2018-10-03 12:00:00  360.0         70.0       0.0   0.0
2018-10-03 13:00:00  465.0         83.0       0.0  60.0
2018-10-03 14:00:00    NaN          NaN       NaN   NaN
2018-10-03 15:00:00  540.0        127.0       0.0  50.0
2018-10-03 16:00:00  600.0        205.0       0.0   0.0
2018-10-03 17:00:00  660.0        298.0       0.0   0.0
```

For a total of 87 rows (here I've shown only the first 12), covering all the days of your csv file. You have `Nan` values for rows where there are no data.

#### EDIT after comments

A note on:

```
data = data.resample('60T').first()
```

In case you have more rows in the resampled time interval, the `.first()` method uses data of the first row of the interval, discarding the othes.
`.last()` uses data of the last row of the interval.
There are other methods you can use `.mean()` calculates the average value, `.sum()` calculates the sum. Use the one which is better suited for your case.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply . Actually I want to write that each and every day first time = o minutes and then next value will be in next 60 minutes (mean 0,60,120 min...)  Here it should be minutes ,in my code it is in seconds that's why results are showing with seconds. (data['time'] = data['time'].dt.total_seconds()/60.0),if I want to convert seconds into minutes. Do you have any suggestions that my first time replace into 0 minutes?

Comment: @awa I modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much You saved my day. This is the code I am looking forward.

Comment: I guess in your code "data = data.resample('60T').first()" this part is not corrected according to your out put. For that I think you have to changed the code like this "data = data.resample('60T').last()" I  think this should be the right code.

Comment: I obtained that output with `.first()`, but `.last()` produces the same result since your data are quite sparsed. This depends on what you want, you can use the method you prefer.

Comment: when I obtained with output with .first(), it didn't come output as your output. Then I changed the code into .last(). It came. According to you both will be corrected. So thank you for helping me to solve the issue.